# Fastest way to create a backup db

Tags: mongodb, backup, azure-cosmosdb

I have a production mongo DocumentDb instance, and a development one.
I would like to create a backup daily (for development purposes) from prod to dev.
When I do it with mongodump and mongorestore it takes quite a long while, since I can't do it locally (as I don't have ssh access to the document db server), only remotely.

Is there a faster way?

Comment: Have you been through the options presented in the [MongoDB Backup Methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/) documentation?

Comment: I have been using mongodump, but it takes quite a while. I was wondering if there was a faster way -- maybe duplicating azure disks.

Comment: I think this question is outside the scope of stackoverflow, as it is not about programming but about database administration really. As such, I'm going to recommend it be migrated to [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: is there a way to first copy the dump file to the db server and then run mongorestore on it locally?

Comment: Lev: running mongodump and mongorestore locally on the db server would make it _much_ faster.

Comment: But how can I do that? I don't have ssh access to document db server.

Comment: Offtopic: better on dba.stackexchange.com (or server fault)